# Una función personal en MariaDB me da un error que en MySQL no, ¿qué podrá ser?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Cordial saludo.

Un compañero me ayudo en crear una función que requiero para obtener el digito de verificación de N.I.T.s en Colombia, me trabaja muy bien, pero note que en donde tengo MariaDB me da un error y no he podido resolver, el amigo me dice que no ha trabajado con Maria y no tiene idea de este mensaje.

El mensaje es el siguiente: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ' '

No me dice a dónde da el error, ni sobre que variable ni nada mas. ¿Qué podrá ser?.

Este es el código:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `Validar_Nit`(tcNit varchar(15)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE lcDato, lcChar VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE lnItem, lnSuma, lnRetorno INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET lcDato := RIGHT(CONCAT(SPACE(15), TRIM(tcNit)), 15);
    REPEAT
       SET lnItem := lnItem + 1;
       SET lcChar := SUBSTR(lcDato FROM lnItem FOR 1);
       SET lnSuma := lnSuma + (lcChar * ELT(lnItem, 71, 67, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 7, 3));
    UNTIL lnItem = 15
    END REPEAT;
    SET lnSuma := MOD(lnSuma, 11);
    IF lnSuma = 0 OR lnSuma = 1 THEN
       SET lnRetorno := lnSuma;
    ELSE
       SET lnRetorno := 11 - lnSuma;
    END IF;
    RETURN lnRetorno;
END
```

Comment: cuándo te da ese error?, al crear la función?, al ejecutarla?

Comment: Gracias por responder. No, yo logro crear la función, al momento de ejecutarla es cuando me da ese error. El detalle es que no me muestra es qué lo genera, en qué momento lo hace o cómo puedo corregirlo. Pensaba hacer un debbug al proceso pero no se como hacerlo, utilizo Navicat para manejar la base de datos bajo Windows.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MariaDB está usando?. No puedo reproducir el problema, vea [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=22029b145f5e84ccc6de2c7cab2577f0). Cambié la función (FUNCTION) a un procedimiento almacenado (PROCEDURE) por una restricción de permisos en dbfiddle.

Comment: La versión que tengo instalada en mi equipo de manera local y en un servidor DELL es la 10.3.13-MariaDB, en ambas me da el mismo error, he hecho como me indicas, en tu ejemplo en dbfiddle el resultado da, mas en los equipos que trabajo me da el mismo error, ya sea con funció o con procedimiento almacenado. He optado por dejarlo así y pensar en otra formular para obtener el resultado deseado. Gracias.